Invalid parameters in ChromeDriver ExecuteCdpCommand
I'm trying to use CdpCommand and set parameters in Network.setBlockedURLs (https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-setBlockedURLs),
but I got the exception, though I set everything right. What's wrong?
"OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverArgumentException: "invalid argument: Invalid parameters
(Session info: chrome=126.0.6478.114)""
        ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\");
        chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

        ChromeOptions opts = new ChromeOptions();
        opts.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.None;

        Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
        proxy.Kind = ProxyKind.Manual;
        proxy.IsAutoDetect = false;
        proxy.SslProxy = ip_string;
        opts.Proxy = proxy;

        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, opts);
        chrome_id = chromeDriverService.ProcessId;

        var blocked_resources = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "urls", "analytics.google.com" },
            { "urls", "*.js" }

        };


        ((ChromeDriver)driver).ExecuteCdpCommand("Network.setBlockedURLs", blocked_resources);


as per https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-setBlockedURLs, the parameters should look smth like the following:
{
"urls":["analytics.google.com", "*.js"]
}

and not
var blocked_resources = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "urls", "analytics.google.com" },
    { "urls", "*.js" }
};

hope that helps!

no, it doesnt help, I tried this but it's fruitless as well Dictionary<string, object> blocked_resources = new Dictionary<string, object>();
blocked_resources.Add("urls", "*.js");

the solution which you gave triggers a syntax error
